# Как сделать таймер для GUI в Java?

Tags: java, gui

Есть код, последовательность операций.

В частности, одна из операций - отобразить окно коммуникации, и - либо получить ответ от пользователя (keyTyped) и закрыть окно, либо закрыть окно по истечении 500 миллисекунд, если ответа нет.

Каким образом отмерить эти 500 мс, оставляя окно функциональным?

Comment: Какая GUI-библиотека?

Comment: 500 мс таймаут?) или это например?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev java swing

Comment: @StrangerintheQ - это для эксперимента, который записывает время реакции на стимул или что реакции не было. Так что да, похоже на таймаут.

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, примите его и плюсаните. Если нет, напишите почему нет

Comment: @AntonSorokin хочу сначала увидеть, решил ли он мою проблему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как раз для таких целей есть [javax.swing.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html):

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();

Timer timer = new Timer(3000, e -> {
    optionPane.setVisible(false);
    optionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();
});
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();

int n = optionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Hello?", "Demo", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой вариант с `javax.swing.Timer`

```html
public class TimeoutFrame extends JFrame  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimeoutFrame(2500);
    }

    public TimeoutFrame(int timeout) {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(new Dimension(200,100));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        add(new JLabel("type key"));
        
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keyTyped");
                dispose();
            }
        });
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(timeout, e -> {
            System.out.println("timeout");
            dispose();
        });
        
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Должно сработать

```
new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(500);
                    //closeWindow
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Swing не является потокобезопасным. Любые попытки взаимодействия с GUI из потоков могут привести к сбою.

Comment: Со свингом да, но автор ведь не говорил что у него свинг

Comment: Можете назвать хоть одну потокобезопасную GUI-библиотеку?